# Android service stop working after I run another app/game

Tags: android, service

do you have any idea what can bee root cause of my Android app service stop working when i run random another app/game?

I do not have code available, i just need causes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service runs in your app process. If your app is garbage collected, the service will stop until:

- You start the service in new process via manifest file declaration
- You make the service sticky (recommended).

go ahead and research above two and let me know if you would like more explanation or code

**UPDATE**

If you see official documentation of [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), Google clearly explains why and when service will be destroyed. What is useful in your scenario:

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)

using startForeground will ensure your service keeps running in the same process. some pointers:

- A service with attached client will not be destroyed even on low memory scenarios
- A service will be killed in low memory scenarios, regardless of the process. Running in a different process is better but does not guarantee it won't be destroyed by system.
- Don't use system.exit(0) to end your app. call finish() on activity.
- Starting sticky service just ensures that service is restarted when memory is freed.

hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for answer. is it possible to make it like process will not be exiting? Is there any option to check if process is going down and revoke it? What you mean by sticky process?